# Deciphering Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, arm

I just had a couple questions regarding the meaning of certain mnemonics, and commands that are present in the code I was given. I have never worked with Assembly before.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
 traverse proc 
      ldr r0, =21475234
      push {r4, r5, lr}
      mov r4, r0
      ldr r5, [r4] 

      ldr r0, [r4, #4]
      bl traverse 
      cmp r5, r0 
      it lt 
      movlt r5, r0 

      mov r0,r5 
      pop {r4,r5,pc}
```

1. What exactly gets loaded into `r5`? Following the instructions, does `r4` get pushed into a stack, get loaded with the value in `r0`, then `r5` is loaded with that as well?
2. What is loaded into `r0`? Does `[r4, #4]` refer to the number in the fifth position in `r4`?
3. `bl traverse` Since we are working in the traverse function already, are we branch linking to the same function?
4. I'm not sure what is meant by the `pc` mnemonic.
5. What does the `proc` in `traverse proc` symbolize? Is this needed in every function declaration?

Thanks in advance guys, I'm still trying to figure this out.

Comment: It's a recursive function that doesn't terminate. Something is broken here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ldr r0, =21475234
```

This is a shortcut, almost pseudocode.  The various arm assemblers tend to support it.

Probably intended to be used like this

```
ldr r0,=hello
ldr r1,[r0]

...

in some other file perhaps

.globl hello
hello:
   .word 0x1234
```

Basically it means load the address of the thing after the equals sign.

```
ldr r0,hello
...
hello:
  .word 0x1234
```

says load the value of the data at label hello into r0.

In C it is this

```
//ldr r0,=hello
unsigned int r0 = (unsigned int)&hello;
//ldr r0,hello
unsigned int r0 = hello;
```

Because arm is for the most part a fixed length instruction set where the instructions are the size or smaller than the registers you cannot load any immediate you want so when you use a number for your items address rather than a label

```
ldr r0,=0x12345678
```

That is encoded as

```
ldr r0,temp000
...
temp000: .word 0x12345678
```

Load the value 0x12345678 into r0.  The assembler has to find a place near enough to the ldr but out of the path of execution to place that data word, and sometimes you will get an error that it cant find a place.

So

```
ldr r0, =21475234
```

Loads the value 21475234 into r0.

this push
      push {r4, r5, lr}
saves r4,r5, and the return register lr on the stack.  The commonly used calling convention says for arm you can destroy r0-r3 but you must preserve the other registers (there is an exception or two to this) so to use r4 we have to save it.  I assume this was compiled code not hand written and/or it is called from compiled code?

so now we can use r4, this copies the value 21475234 to r4, r0 and r4 hold the same thing for now
      mov r4, r0
when you put [brackets] around a register that basically is register indirect adressing, instead of wanting the contents of that register, the contents of the register are an address to the content you want so this says read the value at address 21475234 and save that value in r5

```
  ldr r5, [r4]
```

did you remove some code here for posting this question?

this says read the value at address 21475234+4 and save that in r0

```
ldr r0, [r4, #4]
```

When the immediate value is inside the brackets that means add that to the register and use that address read from address in the register r4 plus 4.

```
ldr r0, [r4, #4]
```

read from the address produced by adding r4+r5

```
ldr r0, [r4, r5]
```

this is quite different this says read from the address in r4, place the value in r0 THEN ADD 4 TO R4.

```
ldr r0, [r4], #4
```

This would be similar to the C code

```
unsigned int r0 = *r4++;
```

lr is the link register r14, pc is the program counter r15, when you change r15 it is effectively a branch.  The push of lr saved the return address when the function (procedure, proc) was called that way you can return to running code right after the function call.  In order to do that you essentially need to change the program counter to the address that is right after the call (bl = branch link which is basically a function call to some address).  So in arm you can push lr and pop pc, so this

```
pop {r4,r5,pc}
```

is the complement to the push, it restores r4 and r5 to the values that were there when the function was entered, and then it pops the return address into the program counter to cause the program to branch to that address.

traverse is the label or name of the procedure (function) proc is short for procedure.  No doubt an assembler mnemonic which is more specialized than just declaring a label.  A label should work just fine but you may get more help from the assembler if you do it this way.  (I have never found a reason to do that in over 20 years of writing assembly daily, but perhaps others have).

bl traverse, this is a recursive call.  Not sure how you are getting out of this, did you post all of the code?

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much dwelch! Your response carried a detailed and  informative answer to my questions. It definitely cleared up a lot. However, I just had one more question. You mentioned that 

ldr r0, [r4, #4]

will load into r0, the address of r4 +4. Since r4 is in the stack, will adding +4 to the address of r4 give the address of r5 in the stack? 

I have not left out any of the code. We were given this as an exercise to write in C, and then explain in our own words as to how this code works/the purpose of the program. 

Thank you again for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: r4 is a register, a copy of it is on the stack.  Just like r0 and r4 for some period of time in this code hold the same value.  The stack is just memory (some bits) and a register is some bits, they are separate.  The purpose for putting the value on the stack is to insure that we put back r4 the way we found it when we finish with the function, basically we dont want to touch that value on the stack.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thanks dwelch :)